# Absolute positioning not working

Tags: css

So I'm working with bootstrap and then I have this images which I want to put on the top right part of the page but it seems that `position:absolute` is not working so I don't know what I'm missing here. I've googled many times but gives me no luck, I have the same code tho. And also I've tried some of those alternatives or tips and tricks but still doesn't work. So here is my code html.

```
   <body>
   <img id="swirl-left" src="assets/images/swirl1-panel1.png">
   <img id="swirl-right" src="assets/images/swirl2-panel1.png">
```

This is the html structure of my images and I have this css:

```
   #swirl-left { position:absolute; left:0; top:-10px;z-index: 2;}
   #swirl-right { position:absolute; right:0;top:-11px; z-index: 1;}
```

I tried `float:right` but still doesn't make it work. I got this output as of now.

[image]

So when I re-size the browser it goes with it.I want it to stuck on the top right part of the page.  What I'm missing? If I adjust the browser the images moves with it. It takes me an hour so any help will be appreaciated.

Comment: Please create a code snippet, a jsFiddle or post a link to your website.

Answer (score 0):

Your code [works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/3zxkb7t7/) to pin images to the top-left and top-right corners, if the images are smaller than the body tag.

How large are the images you're using, and how wide is your `<body>`? 
You aren't setting any specific values, so the images are appearing at full size.

Your "output" image looks like all images are the same size as the body, so they're just piled on top of each other.

If you give them all specific width/height attributes in CSS it should work.
In this [2nd example](http://jsfiddle.net/3zxkb7t7/1/), the images are actually 500x500, which would overlap at full-size, but the CSS `width` attribute makes them fit properly. You can either use a fixed pixel value, or a percentage if you want the image to be responsive.

```
body {
    width: 900px;    
}

#swirl-left { 
    width: 150px;
    position:absolute; 
    left:0; 
    top:-10px;
}

#swirl-right { 
    width: 150px;
    position:absolute; 
    right:0;
    top:-10px;
}
```

Or, since you're using Bootstrap, you could use a class on your `img` tag to describe the size & # of columns you want the image to take up, like `col-sm-2` or something.

```
 <img id="swirl-left" class="col-sm-2" src="assets/images/swirl1-panel1.png">
 <img id="swirl-right" class="col-sm-2" src="assets/images/swirl2-panel1.png">
```

Comment: But why is that upon re-size of the the images goes with it. It doesn't stuck on one place.